# How do I join a model to a parent model before/after using `objects.values()`?

Tags: django

I have a model called `Model`. Here's my query so far.

`Model.objects.values(*list_of_fields_I_want_to_query)`

In that list of fields is one named `parent_model_fk`, wbich is a foreign key that links to the model `ParentModel`.

Given the above, what is the Django equivalent of running this SQL query?

```
SELECT a.parent_model_fk, a.col1, a.col2, b.col1 
FROM model a
INNER JOIN parent_model b
ON a.parent_model_fk = b.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this - see the [documentation on spanning relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

```
Model.objects.values(
    'parent_model_fk', 'parent_model_fk__col1', 'parent_model_fk__col2', 'col1')
```

Assuming that your foreign key field is `parent_model_fk` (the convention would be to call it `parent_model` instead).